# VS Code remote development extensions not working across different clients

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using VS Code remote development to connect to a server hosted on Ubuntu. I have two different clients on my local machines: a Mac and a Windows laptop. I can use the basic functions of VS Code on both clients, but some extensions that I installed on the server do not work across different clients.

For example, I installed the Python extension on the server from my Mac client. It works fine on the Mac client, but when I switch to the Windows client, it does not work at all.

Is this a bug or a limitation of VS Code remote development? How can I fix it?

Logs from `Output->Remote Server`:

```
2023-02-25 18:34:43.623 [info] Extension host agent started.
2023-02-25 18:34:43.780 [info] Marked extension as uninstalled ms-python.python-2022.16.1
2023-02-25 18:34:43.781 [info] Marked extension as uninstalled ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.1.10
2023-02-25 18:34:43.781 [info] Marked extension as uninstalled ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.8.1002431955
2023-02-25 18:34:43.781 [info] Marked extension as uninstalled ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.9
2023-02-25 18:34:43.787 [info] Deleted from disk ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow /home/xhpan/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow-0.1.5
2023-02-25 18:34:43.813 [info] Deleted from disk ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers /home/xhpan/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.14
2023-02-25 18:34:43.842 [info] Deleted from disk ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags /home/xhpan/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags-0.1.6
2023-02-25 18:34:43.933 [info] Deleted from disk ms-toolsai.jupyter /home/xhpan/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206
2023-02-25 18:34:43.988 [info] Deleted from disk ms-python.isort /home/xhpan/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.isort-2022.8.0
2023-02-25 18:34:44.006 [info] Deleted from disk ms-python.vscode-pylance /home/xhpan/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.2.40
2023-02-25 18:34:44.010 [info] Deleted from disk ms-python.python /home/xhpan/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0
2023-02-25 18:34:44.712 [info] [127.0.0.1][4de3c107][ManagementConnection] New connection established.
2023-02-25 18:34:44.714 [info] [127.0.0.1][ca6b243b][ExtensionHostConnection] New connection established.
2023-02-25 18:34:44.725 [info] [127.0.0.1][ca6b243b][ExtensionHostConnection] <2579377> Launched Extension Host Process.
2023-02-25 18:39:43.624 [info] New EH opened, aborting shutdown
```

Comment: any useful info in the output logs?

Comment: @user I added some logs and found that my extensions were automatically marked as uninstalled and deleted. I don’t know why.